# Error extracting dictionary items in zip method inside a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, python-zip

I am trying to extract four variables in a for loop using zip method().

```
for actual,pred,key,val in zip(actual,pred,dict.items()):
```

But I am getting an error saying that the zip returns only 3 values instead of four.

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)
```

What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You pass 3 iterates to *zip()*. Therefore it will return 3 values. The value returned from _dict.items() will be a key/value tuple.

Here are two options:

```
for actual, pred, (key,val) in zip(actual, pred, _dict.items()):


for actual, pred, t in zip(actual, pred, _dict.items()):
    key, val = t
```